# KVM/libvirt: how to migrate between 2 hosts with different CPUs

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I tried to migrate my KVM host from a host with AMD cpu to a host with Intel CPU but when I run `virsh start guest_name` I got `error: unsupported configuration: CPU model ... is not supported by hypervisor`.

I know that KVM supports such a migration (in the FAQ they even talk about live migration between 64 bit AMD/Intel CPUs). What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should edit the  part of the xml definition of your guest so that it contains a subset of CPU capabilities that are found in both CPUs (Intel and AMD). You can use `virsh` to find this subset. Here's how:

#### At the 1st host

```
$ virsh capabilities | virsh cpu-baseline /dev/stdin > /tmp/host1.xml

# copy this file to Host#2 -- e.g.:
$ scp /tmp/host1.xml $HOST2:/tmp/host1.xml
```

#### Everything else happens at the 2nd host

```
$ virsh capabilities | virsh cpu-baseline /dev/stdin > /tmp/host2.xml
$ cat /tmp/host1.xml /tmp/host2.xml > /tmp/both-cpus.xml
```

Now edit `both-cpus.xml` and:

1. keep only the `<cpu>....</cpu>` sections
2. from these sections remove the lines with `<vendor>....</vendor>`

Finally run this:

```
$ virsh cpu-baseline /tmp/both-cpus.xml
```

If you get this error *"XML error: Missing CPU architecture"* add `<arch>x86_64</arch>` in both `<cpu>...</cpu>` sections. Ofcourse `x86_64` is for modern AMD and Intel CPUs, if you work with some other architecture adjust appropriately (thanks to [harald](https://serverfault.com/users/241256/harald) for this tip).

The output of the above command must be used inside the xml definitions of the guest.

#### References

- https://www.berrange.com/posts/2010/02/15/guest-cpu-model-configuration-in-libvirt-with-qemukvm/
- https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2011-March/msg01022.html

Comment: To get this to work I had to add "<arch>x86_64</arch>" to both <cpu>...</cpu> sections. Otherwise, virsh cpu-baseline spat out "error: XML error: Missing CPU architecture". This is with libvirt 4.4.0 on Arch.

Comment: to get this to work I had to remove mode='custom' of cpu attribute and then add <arch>x86_64</arch>

Comment: It might be better to use 'source host' and 'destination host' instead of '1st host' and '2nd host.' 
Or 'source' and 'target.'

Comment: Nice idea @mr.zog. Edit my answer and I'll accept it (will also give you some points I think)